# PyCharm - $PATH on OS X

Tags: pycharm

I need to debug an py-script in PyCharm that makes use of unix binaries like "which, grep" and so on.

If I start the py-script from Terminal (bash), unix binaries are found and all works like expected.
If I start the script from PyCharm "Debug" or "Run", there seems to be no "PATH" set => the unix binaries were not found.

Am I missing sth.?

Comment: That's some longstanding bug! Here's a Youtrack reference, vote: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-17816

Comment: If using zsh, all JetBrains products setup $PATH incorrectly, affecting both the builtin terminal and running/debugging files in the IDE. You can see if this bug is affecting you by creating a pycharm file with `import os; print(os.getenv('PATH’,’’)`, running it, and comparing output to `echo $PATH` in the builtin terminal and an OS shell. I have a fix on *nix/mac here (stackoverflow.com/a/51006003/1089228). Note: their bash startup file execution is set up correctly - if you are having problems with another shell, the above answer should provide enough info to guide you to a solution.

Answer (score 17):

Add the PATH environment variable to your Run Configuration (Run->Edit Configurations…) like this: `/usr/local/bin:$PATH`

Comment: I had similar problems (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20333530), your answer helped me a lot, but it was not detailed, so I updated it a little.

Comment: As @akaRem noticed, PyCharm does *not* expand `$PATH`.

Comment: It does. It just doesn't recognize any modifications made for your shell.

Comment: BUT How to set PATH globally ?

Comment: Where exactly in the run configuration dialog does this go?

Comment: @Kambysese "Environment variables".

Comment: This issue seems to rear its head from time to time and happens for me with the latest 2018.3.2 version of Pycharm. Adding the $PATH environment variable with :/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin fixes it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new environment variable in your run configuration named PATH, and set it equal to the output of running `echo $PATH` on your command line. This will let you get around the issue.

Answer (score -2):

I have had to manually symlink binaries that are in your PATH, but not in /usr/bin/.  For example, scripts running 'ffmpeg' in pycharm will not see /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg but after symlinking will be able to see /use/bin/ffmpeg.  This is a python subprocess issue (they don't consult your .bashrc as bash does).

Comment: bash does *not* look into the `.bashrc` when resolving paths. It looks at the `PATH` environment variable, just as subprocess. Try running `source ~/.bashrc && pycharm` and see if that helps.