# pycallgraph with pycharm does not work

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm using mac os x and trying to setup pycallgraph.
Ive installed pycallgraph with pip and graphviz with homebrew.
Everything works from shell. 
But not from pycharm.

```
from pycallgraph import PyCallGraph
from pycallgraph import Config
from pycallgraph import GlobbingFilter
from pycallgraph.output import GraphvizOutput


config = Config()
config.trace_filter = GlobbingFilter(exclude=[
     'pycallgraph.*',
])

graphviz = GraphvizOutput(output_file='filter_exclude.png')

with PyCallGraph(output=graphviz, config=config):
    def my_fun(): 
        print "HELLO"
    my_fun()
```

---

```
/Users/user/Projects/py27/bin/python /Users/user/Projects/py27_django/test2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Projects/py27_django/test2.py", line 15, in <module>
    with PyCallGraph(output=graphviz, config=config):
  File "/Users/user/Projects/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pycallgraph/pycallgraph.py", line 32, in __init__
    self.reset()
  File "/Users/user/Projects/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pycallgraph/pycallgraph.py", line 53, in reset
    self.prepare_output(output)
  File "/Users/user/Projects/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pycallgraph/pycallgraph.py", line 97, in prepare_output
    output.sanity_check()
  File "/Users/user/Projects/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pycallgraph/output/graphviz.py", line 63, in sanity_check
    self.ensure_binary(self.tool)
  File "/Users/user/Projects/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pycallgraph/output/output.py", line 96, in ensure_binary
    'The command "{}" is required to be in your path.'.format(cmd))
pycallgraph.exceptions.PyCallGraphException: The command "dot" is required to be in your path.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

---

Here:
`/Users/user/Projects/py27/` -> virtualenv dir
`/Users/user/Projects/py27_django/` -> project dir

---

What does it want from me?

Comment: It wants the `dot` command (from graphviz) to be in your path. If you start a terminal and do `which dot`, does it find the `dot` binary you installed with homebrew?

Comment: Chances are you're running into this issue: [PyCharm - $PATH on OS X](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8732119/pycharm-path-on-os-x)

Comment: @LukasGraf yes, of course: it is `/usr/local/bin/dot`. Everything works fine from shell, as I said. It is clear, that I must add this path somewhere, but where??

Comment: See the question I linked and the answers to it: homebrew links packages to `/usr/local/bin`, which isn't in the default `$PATH`. Your `.bash_profile` probably adds it to `$PATH`, but that only applies to terminals. Append `/usr/local/bin/` to your `$PATH` in your PyCharm configuration as described in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14961166/1599111), and you should be fine.

Comment: @LukasGraf yes, thats it, but solution was not clear, and it was hard to fix my problem. Now everything works. Thank you very much!

Comment: I would have suggested to mark your question as a duplicate and upvote the other guy's answer, but I see you already posted an answer of your own.

Comment: @LukasGraf How do you think, shall I duplicate my answer on that question?

Comment: I would much rather edit `Kentzo`'s answer and add in the details from your answer. Doesn't get you any reputation, but it'll be better for anyone that finds that question.

Comment: @LukasGraf Thank you for mentioning graphviz. Boy, I had trouble figuring out where `dot` comes from

Comment: Note: the mentioned fix only addresses 1 dir, not the root problem. If you have other things on your path that you need, like pyenv, other local binary dirs, etc., you should fix the root problem - the $PATH. This problem affects all JetBrains product and affects the builtin terminal and run/debug cmds. I have a fix for zsh on *nix/mac here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51006002) with enough detail that you should be able to duplicate the solution in bash or whatever shell you use.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**The answer is:**

In menubar:
`Pycharm` -> `Run` -> `Edit Configurations...`

In dialog:
for selected `.py` file or for Defaults/Python:

Environment field group:

`Environment variables` > `...` -> `+` ->
Add entry:
Name: `PATH`
Value: `/usr/local/bin`

`Include print environment variables` should be selected

Comment: Actually, value should be `/usr/local/bin:$PATH` - otherwise you drop the contents of your default `$PATH` (unless PyCharm appends to it by default).

Comment: @LukasGraf To be honest, I don't really understand, what exactly I did, but it works. :( How to check, did I drop contents of $PATH?

Comment: @LukasGraf `/usr/local/bin:$PATH` works too. I suppose, that this is more correct value, so I've updated my answer.

Comment: To check: Print the contents of `os.env['PATH']` *before* and *after* you modify your PyCharm configuration. Everything that was in there before should still be in there afterwards.

Comment: @LukasGraf before +$PATH: 
`/usr/local/bin:/Users/user/Projects/py27/bin` after +$PATH: 
`/usr/local/bin:$PATH:/Users/user/Projects/py27/bin` -> I think $PATH needs to be removed.

Answer (score 35):

Install **graphviz** in MacOS by using:

`brew install graphviz`

or in Ubuntu by using:

`sudo apt-get install graphviz`

Then you can test **dot** by using:

`dot -v`

You can also download pkg from [here](http://www.graphviz.org/Download_macos.php)

Comment: The problem was with running it from pyCharm. But still thanks for commenting.

Comment: Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install graphviz`

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, this is a behaviour which two other users have filed as an Issue in PyCharm's bugtracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-17816

I'll update this post if the developers comment there.

[Update] On September 22nd 2016, Pycharm developers offered a fix in the Early Access version. https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2016/09/pycharm-2016-3-eap-is-available-with-initial-support-for-python-3-6/, but this does not seem to have fixed the problem yet.

Comment: Upvoted: it's really an answer, at least on OS X. Vote!

Answer (score 0):

This process worked for my environment; I got the same "dot" error after I compiled.  Unfortunately, I was looking for a visual representation of the code which shows inheritance, function calls, more like a flow chart.  On the UP-and-UP, I Understand what a profiler does this one worked great!

- Pycharm: 2020.3.3
- Python 3.8
- PyCallGraph3
- Venv Environment in Pycharm

For it to work in PyCharm on Windows 10:

1. Install the package under your interpreter: pycallgraph3
   File > Settings > Project > Python Interpreter
2. Install the program called GraphViz (https://graphviz.org/)
3. Under your Run/Debug Configurations go to Environment Variables:
4. Paste the following line at the end of the massive list

   ;C:\Program Files\Graphviz\bin;

After here, I didn't test its validity but did it anyway if it didn't work try adding it to your windows path.

5. In Windows under:
   System Properties > Environment Variables
6. FOR USER WINDOW (TOP)
   Edit > PATH > NEW> add Entry: C:\Program Files\Graphviz\bin\
7. FOR SYSTEM VARIABLES WINDOW (BOTTOM):
   Edit > PATH > NEW > add a New Entry: C:\Program Files\Graphviz\bin\