# PyCallGraph middleware in django

Tags: python, django, debugging, call-graph, pycallgraph

I'm trying to implement a middleware in django(1.4) to create a *call graph* using [PyCallGraph](https://pycallgraph.readthedocs.org).
I've based it from two different snippets found online. This is what it looks like:

```
import time
from django.conf import settings
from pycallgraph import Config
from pycallgraph import PyCallGraph
from pycallgraph.output import GraphvizOutput

class CallgraphMiddleware(object):
    def process_view(self, request, callback, callback_args, callback_kwargs):
        if settings.DEBUG and 'graph' in request.GET:
            config = Config()
            config.trace_filter = GlobbingFilter(exclude=['pycallgraph.*','*.secret_function',], include=['reports.*'])
            graphviz = GraphvizOutput(output_file='callgraph-' + str(time.time()) + '.png')
            pycallgraph = PyCallGraph(output=graphviz, config=config)
            pycallgraph.start()
            self.pycallgraph = pycallgraph

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        if settings.DEBUG and 'graph' in request.GET:
            self.pycallgraph.done()
        return response
```

I've added it to the other middlewares installed on `settings.py` then started the server.
It seems to trigger when the `process_view` is called but when it gets to `process_response` django complains, telling me that `'CallgraphMiddleware' object has no attribute 'pycallgraph'`. How is that possible? Apparently the line

```
self.pycallgraph = pycallgraph
```

is not taken into account. Why?

Comment: There are situations where `process_response()` is called, but `process_view()` isn't, e.g. when request middleware, or view middleware that's executed before your own middleware, returns a valid `HttpResonse`. Can you check if `process_view()` is actually run?

Comment: @knbk yes it is. I've also double checked if the instance of  `CallgraphMiddleware` is the same when calling `process_view` and  `process_response`  and yes it is! So, no idea..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did forget to import `GlobbingFilter` so I had an exception that wouldn't let the code run up to the line `self.pycallgraph = pycallgraph`

Also PyCharm was not properly configured. I solved thank to this Answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20335280/1191416