# "RuntimeError: Make sure the Graphviz executables are on your system's path" after installing Graphviz 2.38

Tags: python, installation, graphviz

I downloaded `Graphviz 2.38` MSI version and installed under folder `C:\Python34`, then I run `pip install Graphviz`, everything went well. In system's path I added `C:\Python34\bin`. When I tried to run a test script, in line `filename=dot.render(filename='test')`, I got a message

```
 RuntimeError: failed to execute ['dot', '-Tpdf', '-O', 'test'], make sure the Graphviz executables are on your systems' path
```

I tried to put `"C:\Python34\bin\dot.exe"` in system's path, but it didn't work, and I even created a new environment variable `"GRAPHVIZ_DOT"` with value `"C:\Python34\bin\dot.exe"`, still not working. I tried to uninstall Graphviz and `pip uninstall graphviz`, then reinstall it and pip install again, but nothing works.

The whole traceback message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\graphviz\files.py", line 220, in render
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, startupinfo=STARTUPINFO)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 859, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 1112, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Documents\Kissmetrics\curves and lines\eventNodes.py", line 56, in <module>
    filename=dot.render(filename='test')
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\graphviz\files.py", line 225, in render
    'are on your systems\' path' % cmd)
RuntimeError: failed to execute ['dot', '-Tpdf', '-O', 'test'], make sure the Graphviz executables are on your systems' path
```

Does anybody have any experience with it?

Answer (score 224):

You should install the graphviz package in your system (not just the python package). On **Ubuntu** you should try:

```
sudo apt-get install graphviz
```

Comment: If this doesn't work (it says the package is referenced but not there or something like that) run `sudo apt-get update` in order to update apt-get and tell it what packages are there.

Comment: If you're in a Docker Container (like I was), I was already at `root` and only needed `apt-get install graphviz`

Comment: Hope I can help someone with this. It did not work the first time for me so I ran `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` and it worked afterwards.

Comment: What if I just want to install graphviz in a virtual environment?

Answer (score 203):

This one should solve the problem on MacOS:

```bash
brew install graphviz
```

---

To explain the misconception for new comer who using Conda. When we run `conda install graphviz`, it install the binary of Graphviz (this is not executable in Phyton yet).

And then we usually will also install `conda install python-graphviz`, this install the wrapper for phyton to run the binary of graphviz, the problem is we might get errors with message "graphviz" not exececuteable.

Thus why better use homebrew to install Graphviz binary and then install `python-graphviz`. Homebrew will guarantee the binary executeable.

Comment: For mac, it seem this is best option. Unless you want to use MacPorts and install graphviz from here: http://www.graphviz.org/Download_macos.php.

Comment: How do I find my bin folder where I have graphviz. I am having this problem and is really killing right now. Just checked I have graphviz 2.38.

Comment: Before brew install graphviz worked I had to run: xcode-select --install

Comment: Thank you. I installed graphviz with pip but only worked when I installed it with homebrew.

Comment: No brew does not.

Comment: This is what did it for my (mac os)

Answer (score 163):

```
import os
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + 'D:/Program Files (x86)/Graphviz2.38/bin/'
```

In windows just add these 2 lines in the beginning, where *'D:/Program Files (x86)/Graphviz2.38/bin/'* is replaced by the address of where your bin file is.

That solves the problem.

Comment: worked in windows, I downloaded 
graphviz-2.38.zip from here https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/Download/Download_windows.html. Unzip it and place it the mentioned folder

Comment: This works for me. I tried to add this to user and system environment variables, but that doesn't work, only your solution works for me.

Comment: this worked for me as well, but it threw another error before working. For some reason It gave me a side-by-side configuration....-error. I had to additionally reinstall the Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package (x86). If someone has the same problem, here's the link: [https://www.microsoft.com/de-DE/download/details.aspx?id=29]

Comment: I used chocolatey to install graphviz `choco install -y graphviz`

Comment: Yep this worked. make sure to download the right graphviz. I also placed the graphviz bins on both user and system paths.

Comment: This worked for me; downloaded zip files, and used this code snippet to point to unzipped contents. Did not have to use the Environment Variables menu to state the path.

Answer (score 100):

For Windows:

1. Install windows package from: https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/Download/Download_windows.html
2. Install python `graphviz` package
3. Add `C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin` to User path
4. Add `C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin\dot.exe` to System Path

This worked for me!

Comment: Also Close your "cmd" in which jupyter notebook is running. Existing running CMD dont catch the new changes in Environment variables.

Comment: It didn't work for me until I **restarted** the system

Comment: This worked perfectly. Just had to restart the notebook again. Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to restart the entire system, but just the python kernel.

Comment: @SujaiSparks - didn't work - I had to restart the entire system.

Comment: If you are using [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org), you can use `choco install graphviz`

Answer (score 67):

Try using:

`conda install python-graphviz`

The graphviz executable sit on a different path from your conda directory, if you use `pip install graphviz`.

Comment: ```Conda install graphviz``` worked on windows! nothing else seems to work :\

Comment: pygraphviz have a [nice big warning](https://pygraphviz.github.io/documentation/stable/install.html) against using conda, Not clear why, though.

Comment: I ran `conda install python-graphviz` in my Anaconda prompt and once the execution is done, just restart the Jupyter notebook kernel. It worked for me.

Comment: I ran conda install python-graphviz in my Anaconda prompt and once the execution is done, just restart the Jupyter notebook kernel. It worked for me. Worked on Windows as well.

Answer (score 26):

**Step 1:** Install Graphviz binary

> **Windows:**

1. Download Graphviz from http://www.graphviz.org/download/
2. Add below to PATH environment variable (mention the installed graphviz version):

   - C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin
   - C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin\dot.exe
3. Close any opened Juypter notebook and the command prompt
4. Restart Jupyter / cmd prompt and test

> **Linux:**

1. sudo apt-get update
2. sudo apt-get install graphviz
3. or build it manually from http://www.graphviz.org/download/

**Step 2:** Install graphviz module for python

> **pip:**

- pip install graphviz

> **conda:**

- conda install graphviz

Comment: Solved for me on winzoz

Comment: Excellent explanation! Thank you~

Comment: Others also answered the question, but this "takes you by the hand". 

Answer (score 18):

This is showing some path issue:

```
pip install graphviz
```

So this worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install graphviz
```

Comment: sudo apt-get install graphviz is not alternative of pip install

Answer (score 17):

OSX Sierra, Python 2.7, Graphviz 2.38

Using `pip install graphviz` and `conda install graphviz` BOTH resolves the problem.

`pip` only gets path problem same as yours and `conda` only gets import error.

Comment: ONLY this worked for me. after trying everything. thanks.

Comment: ```Conda install graphviz``` worked on windows! nothing else seems to work :\

Answer (score 16):

Using `conda install graphviz` and `conda install python-graphviz` to install GraphViz on Windows10 the path needed was **C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/Library/bin/graphviz/** for me. I.e. adding

```
import os
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + 'C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/Library/bin/graphviz/'
```

solved the issue for me.

Comment: This def solved the issue... thanks

Answer (score 14):

Just add below to your Environmental Variable(system) **PATH**
on Windows

> **C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin**
>
> there, you can find  **.exe** files

If not work

Find **Graphviz2.38/bin** folder in your **Program Files** not in **python lib**

Then, add to your **PATH**

**It's important to find a folder where .exe files exist**

Comment: it seems only your post can solve my problem...win10 enterprise edition, jupyter notebook, py 3.6

Comment: You will have to restart the jupyter notebook/annaconda for the environmental variables (PATH) to be re-cached.

Answer (score 10):

Try `conda install graphviz`. I had the same problem, I resolved it by mentioned command in MacOS.

Comment: ```Conda install graphviz``` worked on windows! nothing else seems to work :\

Answer (score 9):

On Ubuntu Linux this solved it for me:

```
pip install graphviz
sudo apt-get install graphviz
```

You could also try `conda install -c conda-forge graphviz` instead of pip if using Anaconda.

Comment: This worked for me in WSL in Windows 10 as well. Installation using pip was not enough.

Answer (score 8):

```
conda install python-graphviz
```

For Windows, install the Python Graphviz which will include the executables in the path.

Comment: ```Conda install graphviz``` worked on windows! nothing else seems to work :\

Answer (score 8):

When solving this issue for myself, I used [this GitHub tutorial](https://github.com/dask/dask-tutorial/issues/86), which analysed the cause of this issue. If we read in between the lines, it says it needs *system* as well as *python* graph viz. In addition to `conda install`, we would need to run:

```
conda install -c conda-forge python-graphviz
```

Then restart the kernel; it works like a charm.

Answer (score 8):

I'm on macOS Catalina 10.15.3, and I had a similar error: `ExecutableNotFound: failed to execute ['dot', '-Tsvg'], make sure the Graphviz executables are on your systems' PATH`

Fixed it with:

`pip3 install graphviz` AND `brew install graphviz`

Note the `pip3 install` will only return the success message `Successfully installed graphviz-0.13.2` so we still need to run `brew install` to get graphviz 2.42.3 (as of 10 Mar 2020, 6PM).

Answer (score 7):

I am using windows10 , I tried installing graphwiz in program files and setting the path: Didn't worked for me

Tried

```
conda install -c anaconda graphviz
```

doesn't work.

Then tried

```
conda install python-graphviz
```

It worked, It seems our python compiler is not able to access the Graphwiz. Hence `python-graphwize` worked.
`pip install graphviz` also didn't work.

Answer (score 5):

1)  Graphviz – download unzip in a particular place in the system (pip does not work in windows ) and include  the bin folder in  the path (‘set environment variables in windows’ OR)   set manually in each program

```
import os
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + 'C:/GraphViz/bin'
```

2)  Then put the model to plot

```
clf = xgb.train(params, d_train, 1000, evals=evallist, early_stopping_rounds=10)
xgb.plot_tree(clf)
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [50, 10]
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue on Linux with Jupyter.

To solve it I've added the dot library to python sys.path

First:  check if `dot` is installed,

Then:
find his path `whereis dot` -> /local/notebook/miniconda2/envs/ik2/bin/dot

Finally in python script : 
sys.path.append("/local/notebook/miniconda2/envs/ik2/bin/dot")

Comment: On linux I just did `sudo apt-get install graphviz` (after doing `pip install graphviz`) and after that it worked.

Comment: @wordsforthewise Your comment should be an answer. Solved the problem for me

Comment: @wordsforthewise that's the answer!

Answer (score 4):

1- first  [downlaod it](https://github.com/tim-lebedkov/packages/releases/download/2019_Q1/org.graphviz.Graphviz-2.38-graphviz-2.38.msi/)(graphviz 2.38).

2- install **org.graphviz.Graphviz-2.38-graphviz-2.38**.

3- now add  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin" and "C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin\dot.exe" to path like [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z-AGmGmR6Z8)
**note**:in windows 8 you must use ; for path example: C:\Program Files;D:\Users;E:\file\

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error message on Mac OS (El Capitan), using the PyCharm IDE.
I had installed Graphviz using brew, as recommended in RZK's answer, and installed the [graphviz python package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/graphviz) using PyCharm (I could check Graphviz was installed correctly by trying `dot -V` in a terminal and getting: `dot - graphviz version 2.40.1 (20161225.0304)`).
Yet I was still getting the error message when trying to call Graphviz from PyCharm.

I had to add the path /usr/local/bin in PyCharm options, as recommended in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20333530/pycallgraph-with-pycharm-does-not-work) to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

After you've installed the package ([link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztViB.png) if you haven't), add the path to dot.exe as a new system variable.

Default path is:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin\dot.exe

[image]

Comment: i don't have this dot.exe file

Answer (score 3):

In Windows environment, use chocolately to install, it will ensure the environmental vars are set correctly.

```
choco install graphviz
```

Comment: this worked for me.  Make sure to run it in administrator mode.

Answer (score 3):

When I first installed pydot and graphviz it showed me the error, but the command below worked for me:

```
import os
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + r'C:\Users\vivek\Downloads\graphviz-2.44.1-win32\Graphviz\bin'
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you should use pip install, and then download another package in http://www.graphviz.org/Download_windows.php
and add the install location into the environmental path, then it works.

Answer (score 2):

OS Mojave 10.14., Python 3.6

Using `pip install graphviz` had good feedback in terminal, but lead to this error when I tried to make a graph in a Jupyter notebook. I then ran `brew install graphviz`, which gave an error in terminal. Then I ran `conda install graphviz` and the graph worked.

From @Leighton's comment: pip only gets path problem same as yours and conda only gets import error.

Answer (score 2):

Add **graphviz** to the System Path

1. Windows - Edit the System Environment Variables.
2. Choose Environment Variables.
3. Select Path - New
4. Add the Path of graphviz

Ex:
C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Library\bin\graphviz

Answer (score 2):

try typing the following code in anaconda prompt one by one.

**this worked for me.**

Source: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/python-graphviz

```
conda install -c conda-forge python-graphviz
conda install -c conda-forge/label/broken python-graphviz
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 python-graphviz
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf202003 python-graphviz
```

Restart the kernel afterwards!

Answer (score 1):

For Linux users who don't have root access and hence can't use `sudo` command as suggested in other answers...

First, activate your conda virtual-environment (if you want to use one) by:

```
source activate virtual-env-name
```

Then install graphviz, even if you have already done it using pip:

```
conda install graphviz
```

then copy the result of the following command:

```
whereis dot
```

In my case, its output is:

```
/home/nader/anaconda2/bin/dot
```

and add it to your PATH variable. Just run the command below

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

and add these lines to the end of the opened file:

```
PATH="/home/username/anaconda2/bin/dot:$PATH"
export PATH
```

now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to save and exit.

Problem should be solved by now.

Pycharm users, please note: Pycharm does not always see the PATH variable the same as your terminal. This solution does not work for Pycharm, and maybe other IDEs. But you can fix this by adding this line of code:

```
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + '/home/nader/anaconda2/bin'
```

to your python program. Do not forget to

```
import os
```

first :)

Edit: If you don't want to use conda, you can still install graphviz from [here](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/Download/Download_source.html) without any root permissions and add the bin folder to your PATH variable. I didn't test this.

Comment: what if `whereis dot` outputs nothing but `dot:`? I am using PyCharm on Windows to connect to Ubuntu 16.04 server and can't seem to find necessary bin folder to add `os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + '...'`

Comment: Rather refer to this issue of mine posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60500987/graphviz-backend-executablenotfound-failed-to-execute-dot-tpng-make-su)

Answer (score 1):

1.install windows package from: https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/Download/Download_windows.html and download msi file

Add in Environmental variables 
2. Add C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin to User path

3. Add C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin\dot.exe to System Path
4. Restart your python notebook.

It will work.

Answer (score 1):

```
#Write this on anaconda prompt in admin mode
conda install -c anaconda graphviz
conda install -c conda-forge python-graphviz
conda install -c conda-forge/label/broken python-graphviz
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 python-graphviz
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf202003 python-graphviz

#check dot -v in window's cmd prompt
C:\WINDOWS\system32>dot -V
dot - graphviz version 2.38.0 (20140413.2041)
(this means graphviz installed successfully)

#Add path to sys and user eve variables
PATH
C:\Anaconda3\pkgs\graphviz-2.38-hfd603c8_2\Library\bin
(search bin folder of graphviz and then copy n paste path in env variables)

#Re-run all cmds in jyupter notebook
#if error occurs (less chances)
#then 
#Restart anaconda and again run all cmds in jyupter notebook
eg.
import graphviz as gp
with open("tree.dot") as f:
    dot_read=f.read()
display(gp.Source(dot_read))
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import os
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + "/Macintosh HD⁩/anaconda3⁩/lib⁩/⁨python3.7⁩/site-packages⁩/sphinx⁩/templates⁩/graphviz"
```

This solved the PATH issue on MAC for me!

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using Conda but vanilla Python, 'brew install graphviz' works.

Answer (score 0):

Mac & Big Sur. Python 3.8.6 w/vs code. While it should have been included in diagrams package, I had to manually install graphviz.

```
(mymltools) ➜  infrastructure git:(master) pip list
Package    Version
---------- -------
diagrams   0.18.0
graphviz   0.13.2
Jinja2     2.11.2
MarkupSafe 1.1.1
pip        20.3.2
setuptools 51.0.0
wheel      0.36.2
```

Running diagrams failed. Then manually ran

```
pipenv install graphviz
```

Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

MACOS - Solution for Monterey

1. Open: Terminal
2. Run: `pip install graphviz`
3. Run: `brew install graphviz`
4. Close: Terminal
5. Open: Anaconda (Jupyter or Spyder)
6. Run: `import os`
7. `os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + "/usr/local/Cellar/graphviz/2.49.3/bin/dot"`

(You'll have to run this EACH time until the bug is fixed.)
The tricky part is finding the dot file. It is the location where brew installs the package. (But it should be something similar to the path that I gave.)
Test by running:

```py
import mglearn as mglearn
mglearn.plots.plot_animal_tree()
```

Hopefully, you are good to go now!

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following command in Anaconda prompt :

> conda install python-graphviz

and make sure to install pm4py in Anaconda prompt :

> pip install pm4py

and in the end you have to try running your python code with Anaconda propmpt.

Answer (score 0):

For Mac users (this worked for me):

```
# not required for graphviz but required for running the below command
pip3 install pipdeptree

pip3 install graphviz
brew install graphviz

# You could include in the .bashrc or .zshrc file to make it permanent. 
# As it may not save when you close the current terminal session!
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/graphviz/8.1.0/bin";
```

Then I can run:

```
pipdeptree --graph-output png > dependencies.png
```

FYI I used this in a virtual env with python3.8

Answer (score 0):

On my end, as suggested in top [response here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33433274/anaconda-graphviz-cant-import-after-installation),
using conda, first I installed graphviz

```
conda install graphviz
```

followed by python-graphviz

```
conda install python-graphviz
```

And then it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For `MACOS` the problem is mostly because that its installed in the wrong environment:

In a cell run:

```
!pip uninstall graphviz -y
!pip install graphviz
```

Answer (score -1):

For windows, these 2 commands work for me, in the power shell running as administrator.

1. pip install graphviz
2. choco install graphviz

Comment: Please make an effort to tailor your answer to the system of the asker.

Answer (score -1):

```
choco install -y graphviz
```

Solved the issue for me. Windows

Comment: There's already an answer for that https://stackoverflow.com/a/77665587/7264739

Answer (score -2):

trying doing this in python
import sys
!conda install --yes --prefix {sys.prefix} graphviz
import graphviz

Comment: Please add more details to your answer, such as why this would fix the issue