# Installing Graphviz for use with Python 3 on Windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, pip, graphviz

So I've had Python 3.6 on my Windows 10 computer for a while now, and today I just downloaded and installed the `graphviz 0.8.2` (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/graphviz) package via the admin commandline with:

`pip3 install graphviz`

It was only after this point that I downloaded the Graphviz 2.38 MSI installer file and installed the program at:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38`

So then I tried to run this simple Python program:

```
from graphviz import Digraph

dot = Digraph(comment="The round table")
dot.node('A', 'King Arthur')
dot.node('B', 'Sir Bedevere the Wise')
dot.node('L', 'Sir Lancelot the Brave')
dot.render('round-table.gv', view=True)
```

But unfortunately, I received the following error when I try to run my Python program from commandline:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\graphviz\backend.py", line 124, in render
    subprocess.check_call(args, startupinfo=STARTUPINFO, stderr=stderr)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 286, in check_call
    retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 267, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\foldername\testing.py", line 11, in <module>
    dot.render('round-table.gv', view=True)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\graphviz\files.py", line 176, in render
    rendered = backend.render(self._engine, self._format, filepath)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\graphviz\backend.py", line 127, in render
    raise ExecutableNotFound(args)
graphviz.backend.ExecutableNotFound: failed to execute ['dot', '-Tpdf', '-O', 'round-table.gv'], make sure the Graphviz executables are on your systems' PATH
```

Notice how what I've asked seems VERY similar to this question asked here:
["RuntimeError: Make sure the Graphviz executables are on your system's path" after installing Graphviz 2.38](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35064304/runtimeerror-make-sure-the-graphviz-executables-are-on-your-systems-path-aft)

But for some reason, adding those paths (suggested in the solutions at the link above) to the system variables isn't working, and I don't know why!  I tried restarting the computer after adding the paths as well, still to no success.  See the image below:

[image]

Although the other suggested solution, which was to add these few lines in front of my Python code, *did* work:

```
import os
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Graphviz2.38/bin/'
```

But here's the issue: I don't understand why adding to the environment variables didn't work, and this is my primary concern.  **So my question is this: why did adding those lines of code in front of the Python script work but changing the environment variables didn't?**  What do I need to do to get my script to run without adding those lines of code in front?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Can you please post the output you get when you type `SET` in a cmd window after setting the PATH environment variable?

Does it contain `C:/Program Files (x86)/Graphviz2.38/bin/` ?

A cmd window must be restarted before updated environment variables become effective!

Comment: It does contain `Graphviz=C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin`.
And I have restarted the command window plenty of times, still to no avail.

Comment: That looks wrong.
It should be only the path, without `Graphviz=`
Something like:
`PATH=C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files...;C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin`

Comment: If you look at my image in my original post, I had set the variable name itself to be "Graphviz."  Are you saying that it should have no name at all?  I don't quite understand what this means I need to do.

Comment: it says `make sure the Graphviz executables are on your systems' PATH`

Thus,  set your PATH, like so

`set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin`
   See also:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows

Comment: Wow, I'm an idiot.  Okay, I finally figured it out.  This is what I had to do: I had to add it to the already existing path environment variable, not create a new variable altogether.  Thanks for helping me finally figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure to add to the SYSTEM path variable rather than current user path variable.