# Not able to print Random Forest Regressor tree

Tags: graphviz, random-forest, pydot

I looked at several examples and followed them but not able to print tree graphs.

```
R_forest = RandomForestRegressor(bootstrap=False,
  max_depth=30,
  max_features ='sqrt',
  min_samples_leaf= 4,
  min_samples_split=2,
  n_estimators = 600)
model=R_forest.fit(X_train,y_train)

from sklearn.datasets import *
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
import graphviz
import pydot


tree = R_forest.estimators_[5]
# Export the image to a dot file
export_graphviz(tree, out_file = 'tree.dot', feature_names = X_train.columns, 
rounded = True, precision = 1)
# Use dot file to create a graph
(graph, ) = pydot.graph_from_dot_file('tree.dot')
# Write graph to a png file
graph.write_png('tree.png')
```

I get this error:

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] "dot.exe" not found in path.

I followed this solution but still getting same error.

["RuntimeError: Make sure the Graphviz executables are on your system's path" after installing Graphviz 2.38](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35064304/runtimeerror-make-sure-the-graphviz-executables-are-on-your-systems-path-aft)

Screenshot of my system.

[image: Environment Variables]

Any help or advise appreciated

Comment: Which line of the code is giving you the error? Are you able to generate the 'tree.dot' file?

Comment: Yes I am able to generate 'tree.dot' file. Thank you for your answer I will confirm as correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to generate the "tree.dot" file, then you can run the following from the command line (in the directory with "tree.dot") to convert to a png :

`dot -Tpng tree.dot -o tree.png`

If this doesn't work, you can also try using the full path to dot.exe:

`path\to\dot.exe -Tpng tree.dot -o tree.png`

Running from Python using
`graph.write_png('tree.png')`  doesn't work on my Windows machine, but the command line operation does.

Solution from [another StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14285099/5755357).