# graphviz PATH variable not found when changing engine from dot to neato

Tags: python, windows, graphviz, neato

Why do I get an error when changing the engine? Everything works fine with the dot engine.

Code:

```
from graphviz import Graph

dot = Graph()
dot.engine = 'neato'

dot.node('a')
dot.node('b')

dot.edge('a', 'b')

print(dot.source)
dot.render('test-output/round-table.gv', view=True)
```

Error:

```
graphviz.backend.ExecutableNotFound: failed to execute 
['neato', '-Tpdf', '-O', 'test-output/round-table.gv'], 
make sure the Graphviz executables are on your systems' PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

this helped me to resolve the problem on windows:

["RuntimeError: Make sure the Graphviz executables are on your system's path" after installing Graphviz 2.38](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35064304/runtimeerror-make-sure-the-graphviz-executables-are-on-your-systems-path-aft)

installed from https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/Download/Download_windows.html using .msi, manually added to PATH.

if you're using jupyter notebook, do restart your cmd window and probably web browser