# graphviz.backend.ExecutableNotFound: failed to execute ['dot', '-Tpng'], make sure the Graphviz executables are on your systems' PATH

Tags: pycharm, ubuntu-16.04, graphviz, dot

I wasn't able to find any solution to this issue for one hour and decided better to ask here. The only rich info is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35064304/runtimeerror-make-sure-the-graphviz-executables-are-on-your-systems-path-aft) with no detailed instructions to match my case.

I am on Windows 10, using PyCharm to connect to offline Ubuntu 16.04 server to try some machine learning classification.

The code is working to some point, then throwing this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/graphviz/backend.py", line 159, in run
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, startupinfo=get_startupinfo(), **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1551, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'dot'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/project/2_input/xgboost_loop.py", line 55, in <module>
    xgb.plot_tree(classifier, ax=plt.gca())
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/xgboost/plotting.py", line 281, in plot_tree
    s.write(g.pipe(format='png'))
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/graphviz/files.py", line 138, in pipe
    quiet=quiet)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/graphviz/backend.py", line 229, in pipe
    out, _ = run(cmd, input=data, capture_output=True, check=True, quiet=quiet)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/graphviz/backend.py", line 162, in run
    raise ExecutableNotFound(cmd)
graphviz.backend.ExecutableNotFound: failed to execute ['dot', '-Tpng'], make sure the Graphviz executables are on your systems' PATH

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I checked  via `pip list` that I do have `graphviz` version `0.13.2` on Ubuntu server. One suggested in the above given link that  the output of `whereis dot` should be added as `os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + 'OUTPUT'` to the file to be run, but there isn't any output except `dot:`.

Locally, I also checked that I have the same `graphviz` version `0.13.2`.

Answer (score 4):

try `sudo apt-get install graphviz`

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the graphviz binaries to your system PATH variable. On my system that's `C:\Program Files\Graphviz 2.44.1\bin\`