# How can I add the graphviz package to the conda directory path when using yml dependencies?

Tags: python, anaconda, package, yaml

There are many [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35064304/runtimeerror-make-sure-the-graphviz-executables-are-on-your-systems-path-aft?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top) about how to add the graphviz package to the right path when receiving the typical error:

```
graphviz.backend.ExecutableNotFound: failed to execute 'dot', make sure the Graphviz executables are on your systems' PATH
```

However, I have to install this package using a .yml file dependency. I am pretty new to yml files and how they work. Does anyone know how I would add the graphviz package to the following .yml file?

```
name: test
channels:
- conda-forge
- defaults
dependencies:
- python=3.7.10

- pip:
- pandas==1.1.5
```

If I add the graphviz package as a pip item it obviously returns the above mentioned error. I run a conda environment on a Linux VM.