# Problem with graphviz, ExecutableNotFound error

Tags: python, pycharm, graphviz

I have a problem with installing graphviz in PyCharm. Im using windows. I already installed graphviz library onto my PyCharm project, however error occurs when executing dot.render:

`graphviz.backend.execute.ExecutableNotFound: failed to execute WindowsPath('dot')`

I tried adding

```
import os
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + 'D:/Program Files (x86)/Graphviz2.38/bin/'
```

as said here: ["RuntimeError: Make sure the Graphviz executables are on your system's path" after installing Graphviz 2.38](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35064304/runtimeerror-make-sure-the-graphviz-executables-are-on-your-systems-path-aft)

but it still doesent work?

any ideas?

Im new to pycharm and advanced coding in general, go easy please...

Comment: Do you actually *have* a `D:/Program Files (x86)/Graphviz2.38` folder on your computer?  There are two entirely separate things named "graphviz" that you need to install: an application, and a Python module for talking to that application.

Comment: make sure using backslash. maybe that is issue I think. i.e. `r'D:\Program Files\...'`

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common problem.  While it may have several causes (see suggestions above), the solution you found is out-of-date.
Unfortunately, there are two software systems named Graphviz. You need both.
Go here https://graphviz.gitlab.io/download/ and download the appropriate version.
To check that you have installed the "real" Graphviz package, bring up a **cmd** window & type `dot -V`