# I'm having problems with Anaconda recognizing the package "graphviz", even if it has been installed

Tags: python, installation, anaconda, graphviz, reinstall

Alright, so I installed Anaconda 2.3.2 and run it as admin, then I tried to import the package graphviz, so I installed it with:

`conda install -c anaconda graphviz`

which is what was recommended in the ([official documentation for anaconda](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/graphviz))

however, when I tried to import the package with either:

`import graphviz`

or just a function with

`from graphviz import Source`

I get the same error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'graphviz'

I tried installing the package again, but anaconda doesn't seem to recognize it (I'm using a jupyter notebook and everything else runs alright). Is there some other path that it's missing or something?

I tried reinstalling anaconda from scratch, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Does `pip install graphviz` work?

Comment: Not entirely, because I need to use the "dot" command to transform a graph to a png from the command line, and it wasn't working. However, what finally worked was doing a double installation, with "pip install graphviz" and "conda install graphviz"... for some reason that made it work... at last.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work, although it seems a bit cluncky... I had to use a double installation, by using the command

```
pip install graphviz
```

It finally started to be recognized, however, I also needed to use the "dot" command from the command line to transform a graph into a png image, and it wasn't being recognized, however, after I made a SECOND installation with:

```
conda install graphviz
```

For some reason, that made it work... at last.

Comment: There are two parts to the Graphviz puzzle, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73653801/problem-with-graphviz-executablenotfound-error/73654783#73654783

Answer (score 0):

Since Conda is a *generic* package manager - not just Python - one needs to distinguish somehow when a package is a Python wrapper versus a library or other compiled binary. In this case, the Python wrapper, which goes by `graphviz` on PyPI and delivers the `graphviz` module in Python, goes by `python-graphviz` on Conda. So, one would use

```
conda install python-graphviz
```

to get this. The upside here is that this Conda package lists `graphviz` as a dependency and so will also install that.