# Best Python package to draw interactive flow chart style in Panel?

Tags: python, panel

I have a hierarchical data structure like:

```
{
 'A': ['B', 'C'],
 'B': ['D'],
 'C': ['D', 'E'],
 'D': ['F'],
 'E': [],
 'F': []
}
```

And I want to use python panel to display a diagram of this like, added another one next to it as there may be many hierarchies to plot:
[image]

I tried `graphviz` and `network` but couldn't get them to install on windows. I am also hoping that I could use Panel to make them interactive? e.g. you click on a node and it will load more information about that node, some metadata maybe. I'm happy to accept suggestions for static examples though.

Answer (score -1):

Graphviz needs to have the graphviz executable in the system and a link to it in the path. To do so download the zip of a release from https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/Download/Download_windows.html and extract somewhere in your system.

See related: ["RuntimeError: Make sure the Graphviz executables are on your system's path" after installing Graphviz 2.38](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35064304/runtimeerror-make-sure-the-graphviz-executables-are-on-your-systems-path-aft)

The script below could be come handy.

```py
import graphviz 
import os
graphviz_path =  "C:/my/path/to/graphviz/Graphviz/bin"
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + graphviz_path

dot = graphviz.Digraph(comment='The Round Table')
# dot  #doctest: +ELLIPSIS
dot.node('A', 'King Arthur')  # doctest: +NO_EXE
dot.node('B', 'Sir Bedevere the Wise')
dot.node('L', 'Sir Lancelot the Brave')
dot.edges(['AB', 'AL'])
dot.edge('B', 'L', constraint='false')
```

I hope this helps :)