# running PyCallgraph on PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, dot, pycallgraph

I am trying to run PyCallgraph module on my application. My application runs on Mac and I am running the application from PyCharm 
Here is what I have tried

```
def main(url):
    from pycallgraph import PyCallGraph
    from pycallgraph.output import GephiOutput, GraphvizOutput
    graphviz = GraphvizOutput()
    with PyCallGraph(output=graphviz):
        obj = MyApp("agr1")
        obj.extract('372','100001' , '999')
```

I am getting the following error ...

```
    libpath/shortest.c:324: triangulation failed
libpath/shortest.c:192: source point not in any triangle
Error: in routesplines, Pshortestpath failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/anurag/Work/quad-projects/quad-hge/src/main/python/extractor/hgextractor.py", line 63, in <module>
    main(url)
  File "/Users/anurag/Work/quad-projects/quad-hge/src/main/python/extractor/hgextractor.py", line 51, in main
    hge.extract('372','100001' , '999', url_list)
  File "/Users/anurag/.virtualenvs/robot/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pycallgraph/pycallgraph.py", line 38, in __exit__
    self.done()
  File "/Users/anurag/.virtualenvs/robot/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pycallgraph/pycallgraph.py", line 81, in done
    self.stop()
  File "/Users/anurag/.virtualenvs/robot/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pycallgraph/pycallgraph.py", line 90, in generate
    output.done()
  File "/Users/anurag/.virtualenvs/robot/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pycallgraph/output/graphviz.py", line 112, in done
    'code %(ret)i.' % locals())
pycallgraph.exceptions.PyCallGraphException: The command "dot -Tpng -opycallgraph.png /var/folders/00/z1t7sw2x1ml1ydhgp084c1xh0000gn/T/tmphl_rNH" failed with error code 11.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I even tried installing `graphviz` on my Mac using `brew install graphviz`
and setting $PATH variable on my PyCharm editor as described here [pycallgraph with pycharm does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20333530/pycallgraph-with-pycharm-does-not-work)

I don't know the exact root cause for this and I am stuck at this for last 2-3 days.

Comment: Please try running your application outside of PyCharm, using the command line.